# TFS 2010 Licensing & SQL Server 2008

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have a question about TFS & SQL Licensing, hope anybody can help...

I want to deploy TFS 2010 in a two-tiers configuration. One tier for TFS and other for SQL Server 2008.

But I don't want to use the SQL Server that comes with TFS. I want to use the a corporate SQL Server that is currently running... This SQL Server is licensed per User.

My question is... Does TFS CALs give SQL Server CALs when not using the SQL Server that comes with TFS? Do I need additional SQL Srver CAL for every TFS CAL in this scenario?

Comment: This blog talks about the licensing white paper for Visual Studio and TFS, it might have the answer for your question: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2010/02/15/visual-studio-2010-licensing-whitepaper-is-now-available.aspx

Comment: Hello Duat, Thanks for the link, but I posted the question after completely read the whitepaper. Regards

Comment: TFS comes with SQL Server Standard. Is that the same edition that's in your corporate environment? If so, then your TFS CALs cover your SQL Server CAL requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Fernando, I asked the licensing folks, and here's what they said.

"No SQL Server CALs are required when using SQL Server Standard in support of TFS.  When you run any version other than SQL Server Standard, you need to license SQL Server separately—either by buying the proc license or both the server license and CALs for each connection."

I hope this helps.